# efficient / safe shell-script to remove all substring matches from a delimited split string?

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sed

For a string split by a delimiter, ":", what's the best way to match all SUBSTRINGS, between delimiters, that contain a different string, "XXX".

So for example to start with

```
/aa/:/a/b/XXX/:/bb/bb:/c/XXXd/e/f/:/cc/cc/
```

remove all the "XXX" containing parts -- which can be any # of instances, in any position -- to end up with

```
/aa/:/bb/bb:/cc/cc/
```

can bash do this directly?  better with awk or sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every entry you want to eliminate is a sequence of non-`:` which contains `XXX`, which in regex world is `[^:]*XXX[^:]*`

But you also want to eliminate the `:` that follows it, and this means you want to match and eliminate `[^:]*XXX[^:]*:`.

Actually, that would not allow you to eliminate a field containing `XXX` if it happens to be the last; to fix this, you want to match the end of line as an alternative to the closing `:`, so the command is

```bash
sed -E 's/[^:]*XXX[^:]*(:|$)//g' the_file
```

However this still has an issue: it leaves a trailing `:` as soon as tha last item matches. To fix this, we can simply run another substitution *ad hoc*, so that the full Sed command is this,

```bash
sed -E 's/[^:]*XXX[^:]*(:|$)//g;s/:$//' the_file
```

Do we really need to `s`usbstitution commands?

Sed has no lookaheads, which means that whatever we match is consumed, and cannot be matched again *by the same* `s` command, even if there's the `g` flag.

On the other hand, we want to eliminate the fields containing `XXX` *together with either, but not both, of the two `:` around it*.

If we choose the right `:`, as I did, than it's clear that if the last field (which matches with the trailing end of line instead of `:`) matches `XXX`, it will leave the result with a trailing `:` (unless all fields match `XXX`, in which case the result is the empty string).

This means that there's no way for a single `s`ubstitution command to give you the "clean" answer for all scenarios of your usecase.

Using two `s` commands is enough to fix this, as I've showed.

Comment: Perhaps the `XXX` string may appear at the start of a line so maybe `sed -E 's/:?[^:]*XXX[^:]*//g' file`?

Comment: @potong, this would still leave a trailing `:` if `XXX` appears in the first field but not on all the other fields, e.g. `sed -E 's/:?[^:]*XXX[^:]*//g' <<< /aXXX/b/:/bb/bb` gives `:/bb/bb`. But yes, using `?` instead of alternating seems a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS=':' '{ORS=RT} !/XXX/' file
/aa/:/bb/bb:/cc/cc/
```

To accommodate the case Enrico mentions in a comment below

```
$ cat file
/aa/:/a/b/XXX/:/bb/bb:/c/XXXd/e/f/:/cc/cc/

$ cat file1
/bb/bb:/aXXX/b/
```

you can do this with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[:\n]' '!/XXX/{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=":"} END{print ""}' file
/aa/:/bb/bb:/cc/cc/

$ awk -v RS='[:\n]' '!/XXX/{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=":"} END{print ""}' file1
/bb/bb
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=':' '!/XXX/{sub(/\n/,""); printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=":"} END{print ""}' file
/aa/:/bb/bb:/cc/cc/

$ awk -v RS=':' '!/XXX/{sub(/\n/,""); printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=":"} END{print ""}' file1
/bb/bb
```

Comment: This still forgets to remove the `:`, if the input is `/bb/bb:/aXXX/b/`, but +1.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis even worse than that, it wasn't producing a terminating newline so the output wasn't a valid POSIX text file. Thanks for the heads up, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Oh, right, because a POSIX line is what matches `^[^\n]*\n`, I didn't think about that.

Comment: Right which means that even if I wanted to I couldn't pipe the output to another tool like sed to remove the terminating `:` as that'd be undefined behavior per POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk to do this:

```
awk  '  BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"}
        {s="";
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if ($i~/XXX/) continue;
            s=s OFS $i
          }
          print s
        }' file
```

Comment: This still spares a leading `:` on an input like `/aXXX/b/:/bb/bb`. This can be solved by changing `s=s OFS $i` to `if (s == "") { s = $i } else { s = s OFS $i }`.